# How to create and execute dsc without powershell

Tags: .net, dsc

I would like to use C# as a the language to create and applying a DSC. The only solution i could think of so far is to call powershell from the code.

Is there a way to do it without going through powershell ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `MSFT_DscLocalConfigurationManager` CIM class and the method in that class to do the same job as PowerShell cmdlets. This needs a MOF file generated in some manner. That can either be using the declarative configuration scripts or hand-made! :) Here is an example of pushing configuration to a remote system. Oh! I am using PowerShell here but you can do that using C# too!

So, if you don't want to use PowerShell to generate the MOF, you just need to find a way to do that in C#.

```
Configuration DemoConfig {
    Node Test {
        File FileDemo {
            DestinationPath = "C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts.backup"
            Contents = ""
            Ensure = "Present"
        }
    }
}

$mof = DemoConfig

$configurationData = [Byte[]][System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes((Resolve-Path $mof.FullName))
$buffSize = 0
$totalSize = [System.BitConverter]::GetBytes($configurationData.Length + 4 + $buffSize)
$configurationData = $totalSize + $configurationData

Invoke-CimMethod -ComputerName Server01 –Namespace "root/Microsoft/Windows/DesiredStateConfiguration" -ClassName "MSFT_DSCLocalConfigurationManager" -MethodName "SendConfigurationApply" -Arguments @{ConfigurationData = $configurationData; Force = $true}
```